# Когда уместно давать названия?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Я уже давно коллекционирую всевозможные ляпы, опечатки и прочие проявления не в меру бурного человеческого креатива. О том, какие бывают названия (для чего угодно), я как-нибудь расскажу отдельно. Но мне другое интересно, когда вообще уместно давать названия?
Раньше было скучно: гастроном, галантерея, кафе-пельменная, овощи-фрукты. Сейчас же дают названия такие вещам, которые и в голову не придут. Например, скажите мне на милость, кому пришло на ум давать названия туалетной бумаге?))) Вот, сфотографировано мной:

[image]

Как вы думаете, в каких случаях уместно давать названия, а в каких — нет?

Comment: Забавно. +1

Мне даже стало любопытно, а что же там такое этот *Попович гарантує*, как написано на упаковке :-). Пришлось картинку увеличить.

Comment: Видел как-то туалетную бумагу "Нежность" :-) .  
Подтверждающие ссылки: [одна][1] и [другая][2] .

![нежность][3]


  [1]: http://www.bizator.ua/advert/consumer-commodities/common/serviette/a844720.html
  [2]: http://www.privezem.ua/product/166
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/H2xMVRW.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Производители бумаги с чувством юмора подошли к производству. Мой братец в пору "а мы с ребятами откроем свое дело" решил на туалетной бумаге анекдоты печатать. Это все на уровне идеи и закончилось. Но смеялись, с какой периодичностью анекдоты повторять, чтоб всем было, что почитать :)

По поводу вопроса. Мне кажется, что сложности возникают с названиями лекарств. Но я не фармацевт, поэтому 100% информации дать не могу. Знаю, например, что широко рекламируемый Алка-зельтцер - это обычный аспирин с лимонной кислотой и содой. А многие покупают и покупаются. И таких примеров масса.

Из веселого. В Мордовии есть местечко Умёт. Там вдоль трассы стоят разные кафешки и шашлычные. Названия разнообразны. Есть "Морддональдс", "Вдали от жён", "Ням-ням" и масса других. Очень популярны имена хозяек. В рязанской области есть еще "В гостях у тёщи", многие острят по поводу съедобности блюд в этом кафе.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу лекарств. По моим наблюдениям, очень редко бывают названия у аптек. Интересно, почему?

Comment: Думаю, что люди ищут именно аптеку, название может сбить с толку. Особенно людей пожилого возраста. Аптеки с названиями есть, но они часто включают слово "аптека" в полное название. Например, "Аптека 36,6", "Аптека Доброго дня" и другие.

Answer (score 3):

Почти всегда. Название делает марку узнаваемой. Не имеет смысла афишировать бренд, только в случае крайне низкого качества и цены товара.

Answer (score 2):

Видела рулон туалетной бумаги, на котором был нарисован попугай. Название было "Попкина радость". Вот такой каламбурчик:)

Answer (score 2):

> Но мне другое интересно, когда вообще уместно давать названия?
>
> Раньше было скучно: гастроном, галантерея, кафе-пельменная, овощи-фрукты. Сейчас же дают названия такие вещам, которые и в голову не придут.

Когда уместно давать названия? Если речь идёт именно о **товарах** и **услугах**, то тогда, когда есть продажа этих товаров и услуг на основе **конкуренции**.

А если есть государственная монополия, то бороться за клиента особой надобности нет. Куда он денется с подводной лодки? Поэтому достаточно какой-нибудь неброской вывески, вроде *"Столовая №14" при СМУ-5*.

Этой столовой нет необходимости как-то выделяться, если все остальные столовые всё равно государственные. Назвать можно как угодно, хоть порядковым номером.

Answer (score 1):

С названиями интересней. И придумать хорошее название товару надо еще уметь. Маркетологи тоже не зря свой хлеб едят.